# How can I set windows 7 in order to automatically save images with same name as image_name(1),..,image_name(n)?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-download

I have a series of different pictures from my site that have the same picture name.

When I right click on these pictures then chose "save image as" I receive a message saying that there is already a file with the existing and if I would like to replace it : also, I would to know how I can set windows 7 in order to not be ask this question but instead to automatically save the new image with an number ((n)) at the end of its name (like file_name(n) for the number n file).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Try below two...

1)Extension called **CLICK AND SAVE** in chrome. Save pictures and images just by clicking on them. Great image saver!

Auto Save,Auto Rename,Download All Images,Filters (filter by url keywords, image size),Floating Image Save button, toolbar,Generate unique filenames+++++,On/Off switch,Saves Images with Click, Alt-Click, Double Click, Drag, MouseOver, or Toolbar button

Easy to use!To download here
[click and save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/click-and-save/dbkmjjclgbiooljcegcddagnddjedmed?hl=en)

2)extension called **Bazzacuda Image Saver Plus** in firefox.

The extension basically asks the user to pick a default download directory for the pictures, photos and images. All images will be saved to that download directory in the future if the user does not select a different location. The second and final choice is about images with identical file names. Options are to rename them automatically, or ignore them so that they are not downloaded at all.To more information  [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/02/26/bazzacuda-image-saver-plus-for-firefox/)

done enjoy....

Comment: I use Firefox and Bazzacuda Image Saver Plus seems to be for saving images from tabs instead of right click. However, I have found another Firefox addon that has resolved my issue : downthemall.

Comment: yes,DownThemAll Has options for renaming and folder choice. It's mainly designed for doing batches of files and setting renaming rules, such as rename the downloaded file by the description, rather than its actual name. 
extension called SAVE FILE TO does it for individual files.use both depending on the situation...